# Bigcommerce if condition check for the URL is not working

Tags: bigcommerce

Can you suggest what is wrong with my code below?

```
{{#if url '===' (first (split (last (split head.meta_tags "href='")) "'")) }}
activePage
{{/if}}
```

I need to add a condition in the header navigation if the URL under consideration is equaled to the current page URL.

But I'm always getting **false** values for my condition.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

url is not a global object, which indicates to me you are inside some sort of non-global context (perhaps an each loop). You would need to go back up to the global context with a "../" (or several, depending on how deep you are). So, your code would look like this: `{{#if url '===' (first (split (last (split head.meta_tags "href='")) "'")) }} activePage {{/if}}`

However, you may run into issues splitting the meta tags like that. I would recommend using breadcrumbs instead. `{{#contains ../breadcrumbs.1.url url}} activePage{{/contains}}`.

Lastly, if you are inside a component here, you might not ever be able to get to the global context with "../" alone. You could try using the `@root` flag instead. `{{#contains @root.breadcrumbs.1.url url}} activePage{{/contains}}`.

If this still doesn't work, you will want to pass the breadcrumbs object to the component, but in order to give you code to use here, I would need to see further up the flow. Essentially, it would look like this: `{{> components/menu/menu-item breadcrumbs=../breadcrumbs}}`

Comment: Thank you Matt for your reply. I am writing this code inside the header folder in header-navigation.html file. I am sorry I might sound a bit weird, but its my first time working with bigcommerce :)

Comment: Thank you Matt for your reply. I am writing this code inside the header folder in the header-navigation.html file. I am writing this code under {{#each categories}}
Below is the code that i have for testing. 
{{ url }} {{first (split (last (split ../head.meta_tags "href='")) "'")}}
{{#if url '===' first (split (last (split ../head.meta_tags "href='")) "'") }}activePage{{/if}}
{{ url }} returns the url in the loop and {{first (split (last (split ../head.meta_tags "href='")) "'")}}, this returns current url. 
I think the issue is with my if clause.

Comment: Did you try the breadcrumbs code that I suggested? Sometimes the matching can be a bit off, and you will need to use helpers like contains or JSONstringify to make sure the whitespace is the same. In your latest comment, you are missing a set of parentheses around the entire part after the triple equals.

Comment: Thanks Matt, Yes {{#contains @root.breadcrumbs.1.url url}} activePage{{/contains}} this code worked.